# How to determine if a motor will be powerful enough to drive a drift trike

Tags: motor, dc-motor, torque, gear

I am planning on building a drift trike and I am trying to work out the best motor to use that is right for my budget.

I have seen:

- a 2000w (48v - 4300RPM - 4.44 N.m  torque)
- a 1000w (48v - 3000 RPM - 3.18 N.m torque)
- a 800w (36v - 2800RPM - 2.73 N.m torque )

I know there are a few variables involved (not entirely sure of them all just yet but working on getting an understanding) such as I could up the sprocket size on the axle and help up the torque.

Just wondering if anyone has done something similar or what calculations / areas I can look at to help make a decision.

I would assume the 2000w would be my best bet but would it give me that much of an improvement over the 1000w/800w (other than the RPM and torque output)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic on this stack.

Comment: For anyone unfamiliar with the term [Drift Trike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_trike), it is a tricycle with hard rear wheels, designed to slip (drift) around turns.

Comment: You can start by using my JavaScript app http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm. It can approximate torque, power, and reduction ratios for various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The other back of the envelope factors for your motor selection are weight, cost, size/form factor of the motor, and capability of the drive electronics. If all 3 of your options are similar across those metrics, and without knowing any other details, the obvious recommendation to make here is to buy yourself headroom by going with the 2kW motor. You'll be able to get 800W out of a 2kW motor, but you'll be hard pressed to get 2kW out of an 800W motor.

Comment: yeah that is a fair point. The 2kW motor is around £120 with an ECU that can drive it. It works out about £40 that the 1kW.